# I'm missing methods in Mach-O 64bit disassembly, why?

Tags: mach-o

I'm curious why when I disassemble my own program which is a fat binary (using otx), once for the i386 arch, and again for the x86_64 arch - I cannot find certain methods which are contained in the i386?

For instance the disassembly for a method isAvailable would appear in its entirety under the i386 disasm but not under the x64...?  Ideas why?  Am I missing a basic understanding of Mach-O structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be inlined in the x86_64 version?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I have my method shown in the i386 disasm, but not in the x86_64.

Comment: I was just thinking maybe `gcc` might use different optimizations in i386 and x86_64. It could inline more aggressively in x86_64.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying.... I don't think its inlining because everytime its referenced there is still a CALL opcode to it.  I just can't find the method itself.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess it wouldn't be inlined then.

Comment: Are you using the [trunk](http://otx.osxninja.com/subinfo.html) version of otx?

Comment: Have you tried Hopper?

Answer (score 0):

The prebuilt otx binary is old and doesn't support x86_64 arch. What you want to do is to download the SVN copy, build a fresh otx version, and use that to inspect your binary.

Answer (score 0):

Since I386 is only x86 which is based as 32-Bit and x86_64 is based on 64-Bit, I believe that 64-Bit has some different structure sizes compared to 32-Bit which could be causing the offsets and sizes to be out of line